# Подбор эпитетов

Tags: лексика

Подберите, пожалуйста, к слову "водка" эпитеты.

Comment: Для рекламы?))

Answer (score 4):

> к слову " водка " эпитеты

Ядовитая и наркотическая.

Одурманивающая, ведущая к деградации, вызывающая сильную зависимость.